# Retrieve the attributes in a UML class diagram-jointjs

Tags: jointjs

I would like to retrieve attributes and class name in UML class diagram using jointJS. Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the attributes of uml diagram is in "attribute" object, if you have created the graph then you can access it as follows:

```
graph.getCell("cell_id").attributes;
```

the cell_id is present in the id property of the graph.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use:
`this.attr('.uml-class-name-text/text')`
to get the class name and use
    `this.attr('.uml-class-attrs-text/text')`
to retrieve attributes.
"this" is the object you selected, see below
`var selected;
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function(cellView) {
    selected = cellView.model;
  });`